# Python Django error related to urllib3

Tags: django

Error:

> ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3.poolmanager

I have set requests module in `requirements.txt` like this:
`requests>=2.5.1`

`requests` contains another version of `urllib3`.  What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add your error traceback message?

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
```

See if the above solves it

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by not using virtualenv.  It was resorting to the system python which was causing this error.